# How do I connect Zoom H1 Recorder to an Android smartphone?

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-6, audio-recording, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

In particular, I want to connect the recorder to a Samsung S6 device I can borrow. The idea is to shoot videos from the phone by taking the audio from the Zoom H1.

I have done this for DSLRs. Is there a way for phones?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mod a 4pin Jack cable to make your phone detect a headset+ microphone combo when external Mic is plugged.

The ground is the first ring (nearest to cable), microphone is second ring.
Last two are stereo audio.

Comment: Zulgrib, hello. I used an OTG cable device and connected by Zoom H1. I then used OpenCamera app and recorded a video. 
The video was recorded and the sound from Zoom was accepted. But there is a constant noise in the recording. I had thought a better, and more expensive, OTG cable will do the job. 

Is that so? Or will I be wasting money? Any help will help my NGO work that needs economical solutions. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Noise can be from many reasons, bad cable, unstable energy, poorly isolated audio circuits, poorly isolated usb circuits.

Comment: Zulgrib, I am using a smartphone, an Honor 6x. DO you think unstable energy is because of weakness of the phone in handling a USB mic like Zoom H1? In short, is a solution possible ?

Comment: If the phone is giving power to the zoom, and the zoom doesn't have it's own power, you may try an Y cable to provide additional power source.